# python list of dictionary in for loop returning all the same values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a python dictionary with the following structure shown in my `data` variable below. I have a for loop I am running that is appending to a list but if you see from the return output all the values in the `dlist` is `{'data': 2}` I'm a little confused why I am getting all the same value for the the entries into the dictionary.

```
# trying to make this dict structure in for loop
data = [{'data': 0}, 
        {'data': 1}, 
        {'data': 2}]

d={}
dlist=[]
for i in range(0,3):
     d['data']=i
     dlist.append(d)
     print(d)

# PRINT OF D FROM LOOP 
{'data': 0}
{'data': 1}
{'data': 2}

# STRANGLY DLIST ONLY HAS DATA 2 IN THE LIST
dlist
[{'data': 2}, {'data': 2}, {'data': 2}]
```

Comment: This is a really common pitfall. Put `d = {}` inside the `for` loop so it will create a new dictionary each iteration. The way you have it now, you're adding the same dictionary reference to the list over and over.

Comment: to really simplify it you could change a line to: `dlist.append({'data': i})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
data = [{'data': 0}, 
        {'data': 1}, 
        {'data': 2}]

dlist=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    d = {}
    d['data']=i
    dlist.append(d)
    print(d)
```

As you are intending to append a fresh dictionary, create new on in every loop.

---

Now to see why you get that dlist, run:

```
data = [{'data': 0}, 
        {'data': 1}, 
        {'data': 2}]
d = {}
dlist=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    d['data']=i
    dlist.append(d)
    print(dlist)
```

This is because of the same key in the dictionary. The dictionary gets updated from its initial value.

Comment: Hey Joshua this was in fact what  I was looking for.  Thanks I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dlist=[]
for i in range(0,3):
     dlist.append({'data': I})
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your list is making a *link* to the `d` dict, and that's not what your want. You have to initialize the `d` dict *inside* the for loop.

```
dlist=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    d = {}
    d['data']=i
    dlist.append(d)
    print(d)
```